# Is glBufferData actually allocating the memory based on the size on spot?

Tags: opengl

I was wondering, if I use `glBufferData`, will it allocate the memory exactly when I call it(aka if the size parameter is more than the available memory at that point it will crash) or does it have some kind of special just in time rule that allocates the memory only when I actually copy the data to the buffer?

To make it more concise, my question would be answered by answering an more practical question:

How much memory on the GPU will this take:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1000, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

And then, how will the occupied memory change when you do this on the same buffer:

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(poly), &poly);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How much memory on the GPU will this take:
>
> ```
> glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1000, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
> ```

There's no guarantee that this will allocate *any* memory "on the GPU". The driver may well decide to put the buffer object in CPU memory instead of GPU.

I will instead assume your question is, "How much memory will be allocated for the buffer object?"

1000 bytes. That's what you asked for, and that's what the driver will allocate.

> And then, how will the occupied memory change when you do this on the same buffer:
>
> ```
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(poly), &poly);
> ```

If the buffer object currently bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` has had storage allocated for it, and that storage contains at least `sizeof(poly)` bytes, then it will modify the buffer's storage by copying the first `sizeof(poly)` bytes from `&poly` into the storage.

If it does not have storage allocated, or if the storage is smaller than `sizeof(poly)` bytes, you'll get a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error.

The size of the *allocation* is not changed. Just as the size of the allocation returned by `malloc` is not changed when you call `memcpy` on the returned pointer. `glBufferData` is like `malloc`; it allocates storage (with an option to `memcpy` into that storage). `glBufferSubData` is like `memcpy`; it copies data into *existing* storage.

Just as you can't `memcpy` without allocating first, you can't call `glBufferSubData` without calling `glBufferData` first.

Comment: OK, I've got it. However, as a side question, I have user generated content which can change in size (growing more and more). Allocating the data initially with the maximum size (which can be a pretty large value) seems like an waste of resources (since most of the users will not generate content up to the maximum allowed size). Any ideas how I can handle this? Thanks

Comment: @Meda: There's a button for asking new questions. Just make sure to be clear about what exactly you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBufferData.xml):

> `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` is generated if the GL is unable to create a data store with the specified `size`.

Also:

> If `data` is `NULL`, a data store of the specified size is still created, but its contents remain uninitialized and thus undefined.

Comment: I've read that in the docs, but still not clear. To make it clear: if you use a NULL pointer as the last parameter, it should NOT allocate any memory up to the point when you first send your data with  `glBufferSubData`? But when you do so, it will alloc all the memory you initially asked for or just as much as you require in your subdata call? This is what I find confusing.

Comment: @Meda: What part of "a data store of the specified size ***is still created***" do you not understand? We're talking about the difference between "malloc" and "malloc; memcpy;" The former is what happens when you use NULL; the latter is what happens when you don't.

Comment: @NicolBolas That part I understood. However, to put it simply, how much memory on the GPU will this take: `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1000, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);`? And then, how it will the occupied memory change when you do this on the same buffer: `glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(poly), &poly);`

Comment: @Meda: Do you understand the difference between `malloc` and `memcpy`? `glBufferData` is `malloc`; `glBufferSubData` is `memcpy`. One of these allocates memory, the other copies memory to an *existing* allocation.

Comment: @NicolBolas *existing* allocation means the bytes are reserved? Could you answer my question in the comment, that would make it very, very clear?